# Angular 2 get ViewContainerRef of the application

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to create a modal component dynamically and append the component to the body or my root element.

I know that when you need to add component dynamically you need a `ViewContainerRef`.

For example:

```
createComponent(type) {
    this.container.clear(); 
    const factory: ComponentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(AlertComponent);
    this.componentRef: ComponentRef = this.container.createComponent(factory);
  }
```

How to append the component to the root component?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the selector in your the rootcomponent html file